# Connection refused exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting this exception:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://www.google.es refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at sdf.main(sdf.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
... 8 more
```

The code I am running is this one:

```
public class sdf {

static String url = "http://www.google.es";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(url))
                        .getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't matter what's the value of url, it won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have Manifest with right permission?
This is an example of you have to do:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Without this you won't be able to have internet connection

Comment: Yeah, I did. The app does connect to internet.

Comment: I don't get it. If your code above doesn't work with any URL, what part of your application "does connect to the internet"?